# Can't get data from a GET request in Angular

Tags: angular

**CONTEXT**

An Angular 8 application requests for an external web api.

The **GET** request result is something like that:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "QWERTY",
        "isValid": false
    }]
}
```

I am calling the api with this TypeScript code in my service:

```
private categoryUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/api/categories?OrderBy=';

return this.http.get<ICategory[]>(this.categoryUrl + prop )
    .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        ,map(item=>item.data)
);
}
```

**MY PROBLEM**

This line of code doesn't compile claiming:

> error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ICategory[]'

If I comment the **map()** line and run it's compiling and the web application starts, but no data are displayed on the html template.

If then I uncomment without stopping, the application recompile, send the same error message. 
But the request is done correctly and I can see my result on the template.

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. How I can explain this?
2. What is the correct way to do the job?

Thank you

Comment: You tell typescript-compiler that there is an array comming from get-ressource. so you would need to access like `item[0].data` or turn array into single ICategory - do the last option if the Get result is actually like you have shown in first json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just getting a type check error. What are the properties in the class `ICategory`?

When you do `this.http.get<ICategory[]>`, the HTTP response is expected to follow the interface of `ICategory`. Check if `data` is a property in `ICategory`, amend accordingly.

---

If `ICategory` should be the actual data in the array 'data'. You can either omit the Generic type or use a correct interface for it: `this.http.get<{ data: ICategory[]}>`

Comment: data is not a property of ICategory, this is why I added map() in order to get rid of data and directely access the array. But not sure I master well this operation

Comment: You could try like this then: `this.http.get<any>(this.categoryUrl + prop).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
    map(item=>(item.data as ICategory[]));
);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the JSON you receive. It starts with `{`. So it's **not an array**. It's an object.

But look at your code:

```
this.http.get<ICategory[]>
```

This tells TypeScript: trust me, the response body is an **array** of ICategory objects.

So you need to pass the **correct** generic type to `http.get()`. You haven't tols how ICategory is defined, so I have no idea of what this type should be (other than by defining it myself based on the JSON of course).